# Remove wildcard matching lines between two files

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove domains from a list that match in another file of domains I don't want to include. For example: a file containing a list of google subdomains, then another file containing a list of subdomains like: abc.google.com, def.google.com. How can I remove all entries from the first file that end *.abc.google.com, and *.def.google.com

I have seen many answers similar but can't apply any to my situation. Most answers use grep but I read that grep is for small files only and I could potentially be working with large files.

Comment: grep is fine for large files, but it uses regular expressions, not wildcard glob patterns, so not ideal here. Unless you write a filter to turn the patterns into REs...

Comment: Though if I'm reading that right your second file doesn't actually have any match metacharacters, just fixed suffix strings? Sample files and expected output for them would be useful.

Comment: `grep` is fine for large files; that's irrelevant. Only problem may be the algorithm you choose; e.g. a nested loop that greps through the large file "once per line" of the list of domains to exclude would be bad. Instead, you can use `egrep -f {file}` with your list of files to exclude. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288809/7832

Comment: ...or better, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83260/7832

Comment: Whether the file you want to modify is large is not so relevant, but whether the file containing the suffixes you want to remove is large is potentially important.  So how large do you anticipate the latter may be (size / number of entries)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any standard tool that can match a string input against a glob, only the `case` statement of the shell is able to.

`bash` possesses an additional construct with this capability, which is `[[ $var == $glob ]]`, so it's possible (but sub-optimal) to do the  filtering in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t xglobs < xglobs.txt || exit 1

while IFS='' read -r domain
do
    for g in "${xglobs[@]}"
    do
        [[ $domain == $g ]] && continue 2
    done
    echo "$domain"
done < domains.txt
```

---

###### Example

For a domain list like this:

```
www.google.us
www.google.com
www.xzy.com
ftp.abc.org
```

And a glob list like this:

```
*.google.com
*.abc.org
```

The code will output:

```
www.google.us
www.xzy.com
```

---

A better solution would be to convert your globs to regexps (for example the equivalent of `*.google.com` would be
`^.*\.google\.com$`) and use `grep` for the filtering:

```bash
grep -v -f xregexps.txt domains.txt
```

Comment: If all your expressions are suffix matches, a simpler and more elegant equivalent regex is `\.google\.com$` (though note that this does not match a bare `google.com`; neither does your glob expression).

Comment: That's right, I only provided a generic example of glob to regex conversion, in case OP has for example a a `www.*` exclusion